# adding zero before decimal point

Tags: c#

I want to enter floating point values to some of the record. So if i enter .(decimal point), the zero should be added before the decimal point. For example (if i enter .2 into the textbox, it has to display like 0.2). How it can be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Anticipated thanks.

Comment: An ordinary WinForms textbox or what? When should the zero appear, when the user tabs out of the textbox, or when?

Comment: its an ordinary windows form only, the zero should appear before the decimal point. When i pressed the . key, the zero must appear before the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a textbox, in it's properties, go to events, double-click on Leave (Listed below focus). A function is generated, write a simple if structure inside it similar to one below:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((textBox1.Text.Trim()).StartsWith("."))
       textBox1.Text = "0" + textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot lalli, its working. But a small problem occur, when i pressed the .(key) the zero appears before the decimal point, but the cursor(mouse pointer) also appears before the zero value. I want the cursor to be focussed after the decimal point.

Comment: You might be using the text_changed event, that will work too (but isn't that elegant), anyways, just add the select trick inside if:

if ((textBox1.Text.Trim()).StartsWith("."))
{
    textBox1.Text = "0" + textBox1.Text;
    textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
}

Answer (score 5):

Just parse the string to a double, and convert it back to string, then it will be formatted with a leading zero. Example:

```
string input = ".42";
double value = Double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string display = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The string `display` now contains `"0.42"`.

You might want to use the `Double.TryParse` method to handle when the input is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

*keypressevent*

```
 // add zero before point
    public void addzerobefore(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox add0txtbx = sender as TextBox;
        if ((add0txtbx.Text.Trim()).StartsWith("."))
        {

            add0txtbx.Text = "0"+add0txtbx.Text;
            add0txtbx.Select(add0txtbx.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```